# How do I get the trains running in the Warren?

Tags: infamous

I'm doing an Evil playthrough in inFamous, while my boyfriend is doing a Good playthrough. I noticed that the trains are running for him in the Warren, while they are still at a standstill for me. I'm ahead of him in the main storyline, but I'm behind him in doing side quests in the Warren area. Am I blocked from having the trains run because I'm Evil, or is it because there's a side quest I still need to do or is it something else?

I really would like to get them running because I still need the Casey Jones trophy, so I don't want to go around just doing random side missions because I want to keep as much of the zone next to the tracks still occupied so I can work on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some side missions in each district, which free the district of enemies and activate certain things like trains. I think the missions to re-activate the trains are called 'El Train'. They should be fairly easy to find, if I remember correctly (it's been a while) when you're in the area you should see a mission marker on your map. Follow that, complete the mission and the trains should be running.

Or, you can ask your boyfriend how he did it :)

btw, +1 for doing the (cooler) Evil playthrough!

Comment: Ah ha, yes, it was the El Train sidequest! It wasn't showing up on my world map before so I didn't see it. I did ask him but he couldn't remember what he'd done.